# How do I get a working HTML5 snippet extension in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm looking for HMTL intellisense and code snippets in VS Code.

I searched the extensions marketplace for "html snippet" and found one dominant extension with 7.8M downloads: "HTML Snippets". I installed it and code some HTML intellisense, but no code snippets. I checked the extension description, and it says, under Update 5, "Disabling this extension as its functionality has been absorbed by VS Code main html extension."

Alright, so this extension has been permanently disabled by the creator. But what is the "VS Code main html extension"? It is called an extension, so I expect it to be in the extensions marketplace, but I can't find any extension named "main html extension" or anything like it.

Without any extensions right now, I have no HTML intellisense or code snippets.

What extension can I use now for HTML snippets?

Comment: This isn't an appropriate question for the Stack Overflow community, however, there is a sister community, that isn't all that old, and it is perfect for a question like this. Its called  **["Software Recommendations"](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)** and it looks and feels like stack overflow, because its all part of the same network. Please check it out if you have time.

Comment: Voting to close due to this being a recommendation for software. This question should be asked on the Stack Exchange sister site:  [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You should be getting html intellisense and html snippets out-of-the-box.  There is an `HTML Language Features` extension and an `Emmet` extension built-in to vscode.  You could see those if you search for `@builtin` in the Extensions search input box.  They are enabled by default.  You can check that they are still enabled by searching for `@builtin` as I mentioned.

Comment: "main html extension" refers to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.67.2/extensions/html-language-features/server/src/htmlServer.ts#L177 which is an extension shipped with VS Code itself. But it's not clear from a glance what are the snippets it supports.